# Add <br> to end of each lines in a file via bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to add `"<br>"` to the end of each line in a .log file, and create a HTML file of the results. 
I have tried

```
sed 's/$/<br><br>/' latest.log >> latest.html
```

After 395 lines, it cuts out. I would just make the .log file a .html file, but the line breaks don't cross over. Sorry if any of this seems weird, I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: You can put the complete file in HTML in a `<pre> .. </pre>` section.

Comment: "Cuts out"? Any error messages? What's special about line 395. Can you/we have a look at it?

Comment: As it turns out, it MAY just be my browser.

Comment: Not just the browser, but there's quite a bit of data. I might just cut the data in half and then run the script.

Comment: `sed` is indestructible. Try other browser.

Comment: I am going to try the <pre> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just use  tags at the beginning of the first line and the ending. Thank you, Walter A.

Answer (score 2):

Well, hard to say bcaus it might be smth wrong with your input file (for example some unwanted white characters).

but you can insert it out the milion ways, the simplest one:

```
sed 's/.*/&<br><br>/'
```

do you need to explain it?

Comment: Please spell out your words in full -- "because", "something", etc. This isn't Twitter where there's a limit on character availability.